# Shouldn't imfilter and conv2 output the same image here?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution

So I am applying a Gaussian kernel to an ultrasound image, made up of integers values in the range of 0 to 255, like this

```
filteredImage = imfilter(image,kernel,'conv','same')
```

using `imshow(filteredImage`) I get a nicely blurred image:

[image]

Then, instead  using

```
convImage = conv2(image,kernel,'same')
```

I get the following image

[image]

Aren't these two functions, used this way, supposed to produce the same kind of output?

Comment: check you data type and the returned data type. I'd guess your image is of type `uint8` and the output of `imfilter` is `uint8` as well while  the output of `conv2` is `double` with the same values (roughly). Try displaying the diff between the two results...

Comment: Adding to what Shai has said, try something like `imshow(convImage./255)`

Comment: Or try `imshow(convImage,[])` which will automatically show intensities between min and max of the image intensities. I think you always should add brackets to imshow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imfilter` and `conv2` aren't exactly the same (imfilter is like `conv2` with the filter flipped). If you use 'conv' then they are the same.

First you can check that you are using the correct image types using imfilter in the other way. Check this:

```
out1=conv2(double(image),kernel,'same');  
out_conv=uint8(out1); 
old_imfilter=imfilter(image,kernel,'same');
new_imfilter=imfilter(image,kernel(end:-1:1,end:-1:1),'same');
```

`new_imfilter` and `out_conv` should be the same. If so, you can do it with your method:

```
convImage = uint8(conv2(double(image),kernel,'same'));
filteredImage = imfilter(image,kernel,'conv','same');
```

Now `filteredImage` and `convImage` should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `imfilter` and `conv2` when used in this way is that `conv2` performs a conversion to `double`...

```
varargin{k} = double(varargin{k});
```

...while `imfilter` does not.

Images of type `uint8` have a range of [0,255] while those of type `double` typically have range [0,1]. `imshow` works under these assumptions and so, if passed a `double` image will display any value greater than 1 as white.

As your original image was `uint8`, the result after calling `conv2` will still have values in the range [0,255] (despite the conversion to `double`) and so will not be displayed correctly by `imshow`. A number of fixes (some suggested already) are:

- Allow `imshow` to detect the range: `imshow(convImage,[])`
- Normalize your result: `imshow(convImage/255)`
- Convert your result to `uint8` before display: `imshow(uint8(convImage))`